# Integrate Google Colab with Google Cloud Platform for more RAM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory

I've been experimenting with Google Colab to work on Python notebooks with team members. However, the VMs that Colab runs on appear to only have ~13GB of RAM. The datasets we're working with require more (64 GB of RAM would be sufficient).

Is there a way to increase the RAM available to Colab notebooks? Like by integrating with other services in the Google Cloud Platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at the moment, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, neither a Swap file is possible to create (the jupyter notebook don't have this kind of permission).

Answer (score 0):

Now it is possible to have 25 GBs ram on colab. After crashing the season then colab asks you to activate high-ram.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can edit (add or remove) ram or vcpu by powering off your instance.

[image: google cloud edit image]

Comment: This is not relevant, as Colab VM is provided externally.